# show all users projects stored in the database

Tags: php

i am making a profile.php page and i would like it to show the user all his projects, this is my first time doing something like this, and i cant find a solution for it 
code to show the projects :

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
            if ($_SESSION['type'] = "developer"){
              $q = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `developer` = '$username'";
              $result = mysqli_query($con,$q);
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
              $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
              if(empty($numrows)){
                echo'
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 newp">
                    <a href = "new_project.php"><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus plus"></span>Add a new project</p></a>
                  </div>
                </div>';
              }else{
                $p_id = $row['project_id'];
                $p_name = $row['project_name'];
                $p_owner = $row['owner'];
                $p_developer = $row['developer'];
                $p_price = $row['price'];
                $p_date_started = $row['date_started'];
                $p_date_end = $row['date_end'];
                $p_paid = $row['paid'];
              //foreach project the user has do this :
              echo"
              <div class=\"row\">
                <div class=\"col-lg-12\">
                  <a href = \"project.php?id=$p_id\"><p>$p_name </br>owner : $p_owner, developer : $p_developer, price : $p_price$</br>started : $p_date_started, ends :$p_date_end, paid :$p_paid</p></a>
                </div>
              </div>";
            }
            }
```

Comment: For the line `$q = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `developer` = '$username'";` you should probably string concatenate that using periods. Are you getting any error logs?

Comment: Your code does show *one* project for the user, doesn't it?

Comment: no errors in the sql, i just have no idea how to loop through the projects and for each project run the  echo part

Comment: @kenney no, it doesnt

Comment: @Kenney i just realized what u meant by that, i put the echo part in between /* */ as a comment for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $p_id = $row['project_id'];
        ...
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the first `mysqli_fetch_array` call after the `mysqli_query`, otherwise the first row is never shown.

Comment: i will try it and get back to you

Comment: @PeterGeorgesBouSaada Glad to hear it. Please consider accepting David's answer then to mark the question as solved. Mine was a complimentary answer to David's.

Comment: @kenney can u please explain why wouldnt it show ? It didnt show it your right but id like to know why

Comment: @PeterGeorgesBouSaada Right after `$result = mysqli_query($con,$q);` you have a `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` which fetches the first row from the resultset. Later, in the while loop in this answer, the rest of the rows is fetched, starting at the second row (not the first).

Answer (score 1):

*Besides the other answer given:*

You're presently [assigning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) instead of [comparing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) with

```
if ($_SESSION['type'] = "developer"){...}
                      ^
```

which the above will fail and everything inside that conditional statement and should read as

```
if ($_SESSION['type'] == "developer"){...}
                      ^^
```

with 2 equal signs.

Make sure the session has also been started, it's required when using sessions.

`session_start();`

You're also open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: I have not shown you the full code, i am 0retty safe, this is just a bit of it. And can u please explain more about when to use = or == or === never understood that

Comment: @PeterGeorgesBouSaada the links in my answer are included. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php